# Difference between 'seem to be working' and 'seem to work'

Tags: word-usage

> 1. It doesn't seem to be working.
> 2. It doesn't seem to work.

I don't know which of these sentences is right—or if they are both correct, what the difference is between them. Can someone explain?

Comment: Did you intend to phrase your examples as questions? If not, perhaps you should end them with a period.  Then you won't get answers about proper word order for interrogative sentences.

Answer (score 3):

There is a potential aspectual difference, as Flater suggests in their answer; but in my view this difference is so slight that speakers are unlikely to make it.

I think the difference is a social one, to do with politeness. Both sentences already have the buffer word *seem*, making them less categorical than *It doesn't work*. *Be working* is another buffer ("I'm not saying, heaven forbid, that it never works, just that it is not working at the moment") to make the statement even less categorical, and so more polite.

Comment: Yes; the hedging could well be self-protective. 'It doesn't seem to work' connotes necessary expenditure / other hassle whereas 'It doesn't seem to be working' connotes 'Perhaps if I give it a kick...?'. Interestingly, the Internet access was down on my computer until a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find confirmation on this, I would interpret the meaning to be different.

- **It doesn't seem to be working?**

"The machine currently isn't in a working state".

As in, you cannot use it *right now*. We need to fix/complete it first.

- **It doesn't seem to work?**

"The machine doesn't do what it needs to do".

Meaning that the machine can still be in a perfectly working state as it was intended to be built, but it simply doesn't solve the problem it was supposed to.
This mean you're not talking about the current state of the machine, but the intention of its design. It wouldn't work *even if it was in a working state*.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and continuous forms of all verbs have their respective nuances and you should decide what you want the sentence to mean, and then choose the appropriate form:

**All simple forms of the verb indicate an action as a whole** - from start to finish.

The simple form of the verb can indicate a habitual or regular action that

**(i) is/was/will be complete/completed each time it is undertaken.**

A: What do you do to keep fit?

B: I **ride** a bike. -> “ride” includes everything from getting on the bike at the start of the journey to getting off the bike at the end.

Or

**(ii) a single, complete or completed present, future, or past action:**

"He told me that I had to visit the Eiffel Tower, so I **go/went/will go** to Paris on Wednesday” -> “go/went/will go” includes everything from the decision being made, bags being packed, going to the airport, etc., to the arrival in Paris.

**(iii) a habitual, recurring, regular or frequent action (that is completed each time)**

On Saturdays, I **go** to the gym.

He **ate** toast for breakfast every day of his life.

**The continuous form of the verb indicates**

**(i) an action that is/was/will be (i) incomplete and (ii) in progress (iii) at the time that is being referred to (it has started but it has not yet finished)** -> I **will be/am/was/have been/had been riding a bike** = I **will be/am/was/have been/had been in the process of riding a bike *but have not yet finished riding the bike at the time I am referring to.***

The continuous form used to be known as “the imperfect”: It was called “imperfect” because the action had not been “perfected” i.e. it had not finished.

OED

<5. *Grammar*. **Applied to a tense which denotes action going on but not completed**; usually to the past tense of incomplete or progressive action.

> 1871 H. J. Roby Gram. Latin Lang. §549 *Three [tenses] denoting incomplete action; the Present, Future, and Imperfect (sometimes called respectively, present imperfect, future imperfect, past imperfect).*

> If it does mean “<s>still</s> **in the process of** doing”,is there any difference with “was doing”?

Yes, in the case of "had been" you are referring to the ongoing work that was taking place before you went and that had, at the time of your visit, taken place. In the case of "was", the work was ongoing at the time of your visit